# How can I use a variable in a date diff function?

Tags: php, wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

I am using an ACF Field to allow a client to content manage a countdown to their next event I am using JS flip clock on the desktop version but as it isn't responsive, I decided to use date diff to echo out just the number of days for mobile.

The site is currently live at [theindustrialproject.co.uk](https://theindustrialproject.co.uk/)

The code I currently have is this:

```
<?php
    $date1 = date_create(date());
    $date2 = date_create(the_field('mobile_date'));
    $diff = date_diff($date1,$date2);

    $difference = $diff;

    if ($difference < 0) { $difference = 0; }
    echo '<span class="countdown-mobile">'. floor($difference/60/60/24)."</span><br />";
    if ($difference == 1) { echo "<p>Day</p>"; }
        else { echo "<p>Days</p>"; }
?>
```

but it always returns 0. For reference, I pulled the code from [here](https://www.w3schools.com/php/func_date_date_diff.asp)

Comment: `date_diff` does not return a number, but a [`DateInterval` object](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.diff.php#refsect1-datetime.diff-returnvalues). Have you checked the value of `$difference` before and after that if-statement where you force it to 0?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without knowing what the function `the_field('mobile_date')` will return ( either a date or timestamp? ) you might need to alter that particular line below but you should be able to use the `DateTime` object and format the difference like this

```
$format='Y-m-d';
$timezone=new DateTimeZone('Europe/London');

/* We need 2 datetime objects - one for now the other for the future date */
$now=new DateTime( date( $format, strtotime('now') ), $timezone );
$target=new DateTime( the_field('mobile_date'), $timezone );

/* Format the difference in days */
$days = $now->diff( $target )->days;

echo "<span class='countdown-mobile'>{$days}</span><br />" . ( $days == 1 ? '<p>Day</p>' : '<p>Days</p>' );
```

Comment: Thanks, that's got me a bit further but not quite there. It is returning 17392 days until 2017-09-08. I've tried dividing by 60 and 24 in case the function was returning hours or minutes but that doesn't quite work out.

The function `the_field('mobile_date')` echoes out a custom field from the database. I've changed this to `get_field('mobile_date')`as that simply sorted the field instead. mobile_date is currently set as a text field.

Comment: What is the output of `the_field('mobile_date')` please?

Comment: 2017-08-17 as echoed to page and copy/pasted the output

Comment: OK - because the return value from that function was unknown when I wrote my answer the use of `date( $format,the_field('mobile_date') )` is not correct because it is already a date - see changes above.